# jQuery datepicker hide options on IOS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using a jquery datepicker. I made a script in which some time-ranges are being hidden when the day is a monday (day 1). On android and windows everything is working fine, but on Safari on IOS it is not working.

```
    $('.extra-tijdstip').hide();
    $('.ochtend-tijdstip').show();

    $('#locatie').change(function(){
      $('.extra-tijdstip').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == 'Schiedam') { 

        $('.travel-date-group .today').datepicker()
          .on('changeDate', function(){
            var datum = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var day = datum.getDay();
            if (day == 4) {
                $('.extra-tijdstip').show();
                $('.ochtend-tijdstip').show();
            } 
            else if (day == 1) {
                $('.ochtend-tijdstip').hide();
            } 
            else {
                $('.extra-tijdstip').hide();
                $('.ochtend-tijdstip').show();
            }
          });

      }
    });
```

My HTML code:

```
<!-- Velden voor een afspraak -->
<div class="col_full nnvo travel-date-group today">
    <label for="locatie">Locatie <small>*</small></label>
    <select id="locatie" name="locatie" class="sm-form-control" style="height: 40px;">
        <option value="">-- Kies een locatie --</option>
        <option value="Schiedam">Schiedam</option> 
        <option value="Vlaardingen">Vlaardingen</option>
        <option value="Berkel en Rodenrijs">Berkel en Rodenrijs</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="col_half travel-date-group nnvo">
        <label for="datum">Datum <small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="datum" name="datum" class="sm-form-control tleft disabled-week today" placeholder="DD-MM-JJJJ" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="col_half col_last nnvo">
         <label for="tijdstip">Tijdstip <small>*</small></label>
         <select id="tijdstip" name="tijdstip" class="sm-form-control" style="height: 40px;">
             <option value="">-- Kies een tijd --</option>
             <option value="09:30" class="ochtend-tijdstip">09:30</option>
             <option value="10:00" class="ochtend-tijdstip">10:00</option>
             <option value="10:30" class="ochtend-tijdstip">10:30</option>
             <option value="11:00" class="ochtend-tijdstip">11:00</option>
             <option value="11:30" class="ochtend-tijdstip">11:30</option>
             <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
             <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
             <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
             <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
             <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
             <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
             <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
             <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
             <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
             <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
             <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
             <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
             <option value="18:00" class="extra-tijdstip">18:00</option>
             <option value="18:30" class="extra-tijdstip">18:30</option>
             <option value="19:00" class="extra-tijdstip">19:00</option>
             <option value="19:30" class="extra-tijdstip">19:30</option>
             <option value="20:00" class="extra-tijdstip">20:00</option>
             <option value="20:30" class="extra-tijdstip">20:30</option>
         </select>
     </div>
```

Does anyone know what is causing IOS to not work for this?

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Please clarify your question regarding platforms.  You appear to be struggling with browsers, yet you mention platform as if you were making a native app.  Working on "android and windows" doesn't mean anything unless this is a native app.

Comment: It is a website and when testing on an iPhone 6 and iPhone 8 it is not working. Testing on my windows computer and on my Samsung Galaxy S9, everything is working fine. So I guess it is an IOS problem.